# Showing $|(p^n)'(z)| \leq M$ implies $|p^n(z)| \leq M|z|$.

Tags: complex-analysis

If $p$ is a complex polynomial of degree strictly greater than $1$ with $p(0)=0$, how does $|(p^n)'(z)| \leq M$ imply $|p^n(z)| \leq M|z|$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

The families $\{(p^n)', n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ and $\{p^n, n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ are both normal.

Comment: This is saying that $f'$ is bounded, where $f=p^n$. By Liouville's theorem then $f'$ is constant. But $f'$ is polynomial so who needs Liouville to prove that it's constant or unbounded?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand your last sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$p^n(z) = \int_{0}^{z} (p^n)'(t)\,dt $$
and by the triangle inequality
$$ \left|p^n(z)\right|\leq \sup\left|(p^n)'(z)\right|\cdot |z|.$$

Comment: Could you expand on the triangle inequality step? I'm having trouble seeing how you go from the integral to the inequality.

Comment: @Mandelbob: $$\left|\int_A f(z)\,dz\right| \leq \int_{A}|f(z)|\,dz \leq \mu(A) \sup_{A}|f(z)|.$$